# f:ajax no renderiza sección html

Tags: html5, jsf, java-8

estoy haciendo un formulario que muestra unos datos si una lista de no esta vacia, al cargar la pagina por primera vez los datos se muestran dependiendo de si la lista es vacia o no. El objetivo es que la lista esta vacia al inicio, se envia el formulario, se obtienen los datos, se guardan en la lista (aca ya no es vacia) y se muestran los datos en la vista, sin embargo esto no esta pasando, la sección de datos nunca se muestra

**Form**

```
<form jsf:id="query">
  <div>
    <ui:include src="../components/general/component.xhtml" />
  </div>
  <div> 
    <button type="submit" jsf:action="#{bean.consult(entitySelector.type, entitySelector.code)}">
      Consultar
      <f:ajax execute="@form" render="datos" />
    </button>
  </div>
</form>     
<div jsf:id="datos" jsf:rendered="#{not empty bean.textos}">
  <div>
    <label jsf:id="label1">#{userSession.user.userName}</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label jsf:id="label2">#{userSession.expirationDate}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Bean**

```
@Named("bean")
@RequestScoped
public class BeanController {
      private List<String> textos;
      
      @Inject
      private Logger logger;
        
      @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
        this.textos = new ArrayList<>();
      }
      
      public String consult(String type, String code) {
        this.logger.infof("Consulta para %s : %s", type, code);
        this.textos.add("datos"); //se adiciona un dato a la lista que controla el renderizado
        return "";
      }
      
      public List<String> getTextos() {
        return textos;
      } 
    }
```

Como observan al realizar `summit`en el `form` se ejecuta el método `bean.consult` donde adiciono un registro a la lista por lo cual ya no esta vacia, pero la sección `datos` no se renderiza después del `summit`